# multiple test cases for selenium RC

Tags: selenium

How can you create multiple test cases for selenium RC using eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate a test framework, such as TestNG or JUnit. Based on these frameworks, you can build data driven tests, or a number of scripts, executed sequentially (or in parallel) using Ant.

Comment: I am using junit framework and selenium 1.0.3 version, I wanted to know weather we can create a test suit in selenium rc using junit, which can consist a lot of test cases?

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing a Data Provider into your tests and having the test methods be executed for the different values in it.

For example, you can have a CSV file with the different test parameters for each case and execute "each line".

Comment: can we use Data provider method to extract values from xml files? without having to use a parser?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the latest Junit version and the latest Selenium 2 Version.
Those two together make it pretty easy to get going.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG has better support for all test automation requirements. Try it.

Find more on how to do this here http://aboutselenium.blogspot.com/2011/10/building-automation-framework-with-ant.html